# Bitrix. Как получить html код письма с почтового шаблона перед отправкой?

Tags: email, битрикс

Нужно перед отправкой письма прикрепить pdf файл этого же самого письма. вопрос. как получить html код письма перед его отправкой что бы там было уже всё подставлено?

Answer (score 1):

Событие [`OnBeforeEventSend`](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbeforeeventsend.php), но Вам придётся сначала подставить значения

Пример:

```
AddEventHandler('main', 'OnBeforeEventSend', Array("MyForm", "my_OnBeforeEventSend"));
class MyForm
{
   function my_OnBeforeEventSend($arFields, $arTemplate)
   {

         //получим сообщение
         $mess = $arTemplate["MESSAGE"];
         foreach($arFields as $keyField => $arField)
            $mess = str_replace('#'.$keyField.'#', $arField, $mess); //подставляем значения в шаблон
   }
}
```

Comment: мне из этого всего html кода нужно сгенерировать pdf и после прикрепить к письму. это делать тоже тут?

Comment: @Tsyklop Если Вам нужно добавить файл, то берёте генерируете код и отменяете событие текущей отправки. И заново вызываете `CEvent::Send` с нужными параметрами.

Comment: а как отменить событие? и где? в этой же функции?

Comment: В этой же функции. Необходимо изменить $arFields — удалить все значения. Не забудьте передать $arFields по ссылке

Comment: Смотрите. Нашел информацию о том что файлы прикрепляются в событии `OnBeforeEventAdd`. Нашел уже готовый скрипт(функцию) который прикрепляет файл и отправляет письмо. Вопрос в том что как сгенерировать там pdf. Вот [статья](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/11948/blog/1623/) где я нашел инфу.

Comment: В чём проблема?

Comment: У Вас есть код — добавьте генерацию PDF

Comment: Проблема в том что в событии `OnBeforeEventAdd` нужно получить текст письма.

Comment: Вам в событии приходит ID почтового шаблона и набор параметров для него в чём проблема пройти и заменить шаблоны на значения и получить готовый текст? тем более что в ответе уже даже есть цикл как это делать